# Как правильно удалить пользователя и базу PostgreSQL в Ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Есть сценарий:

```
- name: Remove PostgreSQL user
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user:
    db: "{{ dbname }}"
    user: "{{ username }}"
    state: absent

- name: Remove PostgreSQL db
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ dbname }}"
    state: absent
```

Но при выполннии выдает ошику что не удалось удалить пользователя. Подскажите что не так?

Comment: Вероятно вы хотели в обратном порядке? Сначала удалить базу, затем пользователя. Если где-то этому пользователю принадлежат какие-то объекты - то postgresql вам не даст удалить пользователя.

Comment: Аа, то есть наоборот? Сначала базу, потом юзера?

Comment: Если объекта пользователя гарантированно могут быть только в одной базе - то сначала удалять надо базу, затем пользователя. postgresql таких гарантий не даёт, у него пользователи глобальны на весь кластер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```
- name: Remove PostgreSQL db
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ dbname }}"
    state: absent

- name: Remove PostgreSQL user
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user:
    user: "{{ username }}"
    state: absent
```